# C++ container - set and object

Tags: c++, containers

I have following class.

```
class Student {   
    //Parameterized constructor.
    private:
       int rollNo;
       char* name;
       float marks;
 }
```

I have a `set<Student> students`. When I insert a student object in set, how can I sepcify that two objects are same. E.g. I am considering two objects same if their `rollNo` is same so `Student s1(10,"ABC",35)` and `Student s2(10,"XYZ",67)` both are same. So when I say `students.insert(s1)` and `students.insert(s2)`, set will have only one object i.e. `s1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::set with user defined type, how to ensure no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114856/stdset-with-user-defined-type-how-to-ensure-no-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and define friend `operator>` for `class Student`

**Example code**

```
class Student {
  /* everything you already have */
  public:
  friend bool operator<(const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs);
};

bool operator<(const Student& lhs, const Student& rhs) {
  return lhs.rollNo < rhs.rollNo;
}
```

Solution provided thermite does not work because compare function doesn't have access to private members of `class Student`. To solve this problem, you can declare `operator<` as friend. A friend function (or class) can access the `private` and `protected` members of the class in which it is declared as a friend.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this in c++ but a quick look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/
explains it nicely.
Basically when you instantiate the set you need to give it a comparison object which "  returns true if the first argument goes before the second argument"

for ints it could be

```
struct classcomp {
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
  {return lhs<rhs;}
};
```

in your case that would be more like

```
struct StudentCompare{
    bool operator() (const Student& lsh, const Student& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.rollNo < rhs.rollNo; //or however they need to be compared
    }
};
```

and then you can instantiate it like

```
std::set<int,StudentCompare> mySet;
```

This wont work as is for your code as rollNo is private. I recommend that you read the page i linked to above to better understand is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is just define the less then operator - if neither of two elements is less then the other then they are effectively equal/equivalent to each other - the "original" thread linked by Daniel shows this nicely.