# How c++ set/map checks the equality of keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

How c++ set/map checks the equality of keys ?

for example in this example :

```
struct A
{
    int id , val;

    A( int _val = 0 , int _id = 0 ) 
    { val = _val , id = _id; }

    bool friend operator < ( const A &x , const A &y )
    {
        return x.val < y.val;
    }
};
set< A > s;
```

because we haven't written the == operator ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::set with user defined type, how to ensure no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114856/stdset-with-user-defined-type-how-to-ensure-no-duplicates)

Comment: Related: [set documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [map documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator==` is not used by `std::set`. Elements a and b are considered equal iff `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`

**Note:** A set is probably inappropriate if you define equality in a different sense than ordering. Equality in set essentially means the two element will have the same place in sorted sequence of items.

Answer (score 6):

it checks `if (!(x < y) && !(y < x))`